# Ionic Range dual Knobs not showing

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a Popover on the products page in my app, which needs to contain an ion-range with dualKnobs to select a price range. The problem is, the ion range is only showing one knob. It seems to only fail inside de Popover, if I place it on a normal page it works just fine. I need help please.

.html

```
<ion-range dualKnobs="true" min="0" max="1000" step="100" snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="knobValues"></ion-range>
```

.ts

```
knobValues: any = { upper: 1000, lower: 0 };
```

Comment: can you share a stackblitz reproducing this issue?

Comment: [This looks like a bug](https://codepen.io/brandyscarney/pen/VwadgEG?editors=1011), could you create a new issue here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/new/choose